# How to put four plots on the same subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I use the following code to create my desired plot for four classifiers:

I have a `df` with two columns, `mean` is mda importance, `std` is std of feature importance

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

'''Function to use to calculate importances'''  

def featImpMDA(clf,X,y,n_splits=5):
# feat importance based on OOS score reduction
    from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
    from sklearn.model_selection._split import KFold
    cvGen=KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
    scr0,scr1=pd.Series(),pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns)
    for i,(train,test) in enumerate(cvGen.split(X=X)):
        X0,y0=X.iloc[train,:],y.iloc[train]
        X1,y1=X.iloc[test,:],y.iloc[test]
        fit=clf.fit(X=X0,y=y0) # the fit occurs here
        prob=fit.predict_proba(X1) # prediction before shuffling
        scr0.loc[i]=-log_loss(y1,prob,labels=clf.classes_)
        for j in X.columns:
            X1_=X1.copy(deep=True)
            np.random.shuffle(X1_[j].values) # shuffle one column
            prob=fit.predict_proba(X1_) # prediction after shuffling
            scr1.loc[i,j]=-log_loss(y1,prob,labels=clf.classes_)
    imp=(-1*scr1).add(scr0,axis=0)
    imp=imp/(-1*scr1)
    imp=pd.concat({'mean':imp.mean(),
                   'std':imp.std()*imp.shape[0]**-.5},axis=1) # CLT
    return imp

'''Import data''' 

data = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = data.data, data.target
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = [data.feature_names])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, pd.DataFrame(y), random_state=42)

'''Calculate importances'''

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
bc_rf = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
bc_et = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

clf = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
bc_xgb = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
bc_dt = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

'''Plot 1 RF'''

bc_rf.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_rf = bc_rf.iloc[:30,:]
bc_rf.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(3,10))
ax = bc_rf['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_rf['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'})
plt.title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'RF'), fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")   

'''Plot 2 ET'''

bc_et.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_et = bc_et.iloc[:30,:]
bc_et.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(3,10))
ax = bc_et['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_et['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'})
plt.title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'ET'), fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")   

'''Plot 3 XGB'''

bc_xgb.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_xgb = bc_xgb.iloc[:30,:]
bc_xgb.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(3,10))
ax = bc_xgb['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_xgb['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'})
plt.title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'XGB'), fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")   

'''Plot 4 DT'''

bc_dt.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_dt = bc_dt.iloc[:30,:]
bc_dt.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(3,10))
ax = bc_dt['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_dt['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'})
plt.title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'DT'), fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")
```

However, I am interested in creating a subplot with 4 plots for the 4 classifiers. I am not sure what to do here. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Without seeing the data, the current plot you're generating, and the a more detailed description of the plot you want, we can't really provide definitive help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have updated the question with a dataset and required plots. Just not sure how to make them a subplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example, which produces 4 subplots. I have not changed any of the formatting, but it is easy to do so. I hope this is what you want!

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

'''Function to use to calculate importances'''

def featImpMDA(clf,X,y,n_splits=5):
# feat importance based on OOS score reduction
    from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
    from sklearn.model_selection._split import KFold
    cvGen=KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
    scr0,scr1=pd.Series(),pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns)
    for i,(train,test) in enumerate(cvGen.split(X=X)):
        X0,y0=X.iloc[train,:],y.iloc[train]
        X1,y1=X.iloc[test,:],y.iloc[test]
        fit=clf.fit(X=X0,y=y0) # the fit occurs here
        prob=fit.predict_proba(X1) # prediction before shuffling
        scr0.loc[i]=-log_loss(y1,prob,labels=clf.classes_)
        for j in X.columns:
            X1_=X1.copy(deep=True)
            np.random.shuffle(X1_[j].values) # shuffle one column
            prob=fit.predict_proba(X1_) # prediction after shuffling
            scr1.loc[i,j]=-log_loss(y1,prob,labels=clf.classes_)
    imp=(-1*scr1).add(scr0,axis=0)
    imp=imp/(-1*scr1)
    imp=pd.concat({'mean':imp.mean(),
                   'std':imp.std()*imp.shape[0]**-.5},axis=1) # CLT
    return imp

'''Import data'''

data = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = data.data, data.target
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = [data.feature_names])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, pd.DataFrame(y), random_state=42)

'''Calculate importances'''

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
bc_rf = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
bc_et = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

clf = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
bc_xgb = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
bc_dt = featImpMDA(clf,X_train,y_train,n_splits=5)

# Set up a grid of axes objects
gs1 = GridSpec(2, 2)

# Get axes objects which you can then use to plot
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 1], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 1], sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)

'''Plot 1 RF'''

bc_rf.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_rf = bc_rf.iloc[:30,:]
bc_rf.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
ax = bc_rf['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_rf['std'], error_kw={'ecolor':'r'}, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'RF'), fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")

'''Plot 2 ET'''

bc_et.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_et = bc_et.iloc[:30,:]
bc_et.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
ax = bc_et['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_et['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'}, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'ET'), fontsize=10)
ax2.set_xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")

'''Plot 3 XGB'''

bc_xgb.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_xgb = bc_xgb.iloc[:30,:]
bc_xgb.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
ax = bc_xgb['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_xgb['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'}, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'XGB'), fontsize=10)
ax3.set_xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")

'''Plot 4 DT'''

bc_dt.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False, inplace=True)
bc_dt = bc_dt.iloc[:30,:]
bc_dt.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
ax = bc_dt['mean'].plot(kind='barh',color='b', alpha=.40, xerr=bc_dt['std'],
                         error_kw={'ecolor':'r'}, ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title('{} full {} feature importances '.format('US', 'DT'), fontsize=10)
ax4.set_xlabel("Permutation Importance (MDA)")
plt.show()
```

The main difference is that here you are using the matplotlib axes to produce the actual plot rather than the pandas dataframe. You would still need to get the data from the dataframe, then pass that as input to ax1.plot() or ax1.scatter() for example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated the question with similar dataset. Any help on that would be awesome!